# Check for Updates vs. Check online for updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

In Windows Update (on Windows 10), what is the difference between the <kbd>Check for updates</kbd> button vs the *Check online for updates from Microsoft Update* link?

When I click the button I typically see no new updates, but I do when I click the link.

This is on a company-managed laptop.

[image: Windows Update]

Comment: Are you connected to an AD domain?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes I am

Comment: Which version of Windows is this?

Comment: so there are two things to consider here. first is that your domain admins have likely set update settings for your system to point to a local update server running SCCM or WSUS (or WUS if its really old). clicking this link will check Microsofts servers instead of the local domain update servers. additionally Microsoft Update (as distinct from Windows Update) will update other Microsoft software on the system, not just the OS.

Comment: @J.Mini - Windows 10, I've updated my question to include this.